# PHP PDO - I can't update the variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to do a admin panel. I used PDO for database connect. In panel, i want to update site title, site url etc. But i have a problem. I am sure that i did all true.

I need your help.

This is admin panel code :

```
   <?php
include 'config.php';
$ayarsor=$db->prepare("select * from ayar1 where ayar_id=?");
$ayarsor->execute(array(0));
$ayarcek=$ayarsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ust">
<h1><center>panel</center></h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
<h2>Send something</h2>
<p>  ADMİN PANELİ</p>
</div>
<div class="orta">
<table>
    <form action="islem.php" method="POST">
      <tr>
            <td><label>Site başlığı</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ayar_title" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Duyuru</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ayar_duyuru" value="<?php echo $ayarcek['ayar_duyuru']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Düşman</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="ayar_dusman" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><button name="genelayarkaydet">Güncelle</button></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>``

</div>
```

This is islem.php :

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'config.php';


if(isset($_POST['genelayarkaydet'])) {

$ayarkaydet=$db->prepare("UPDATE ayar1 set 
ayar_title=sitetitle,
ayar_duyuru=duyuru,
ayar_dusman=dusman 
WHERE ayar_id=0");

$update=$ayarkaydet->execute(array(
    'sitetitle' => $_POST['ayar_title'],
'duyuru' => $_POST['ayar_duyuru'],
'dusman' => $_POST['ayar_dusman']
    ));
if($update) {
    echo "Degistirildi!!!!!!";
}
else {
    echo "olmadı la";
}
}


?>
```

Comment: You didn't say what is the problem exactly here? What do you get from your code and what do you expect?

Comment: You're not actually binding anything, `ayar_title=sitetitle` should be `ayar_title=:sitetitle` (note the `:`) - it needs to be placeholders for all those, not strings (which are unquoted on top of that).

Comment: @Qirel Thank you , You solved the problem. I didn't know that we must add : after = ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the variables for the database query.

```
$ayarkaydet = $db->prepare("UPDATE ayar1 set ayar_title = :sitetitle,
                            ayar_duyuru = :duyuru,
                            ayar_dusman = :dusman 
                            WHERE ayar_id = 0");

$update = $ayarkaydet->execute(array(
    'sitetitle' => $_POST['ayar_title'],
    'duyuru' => $_POST['ayar_duyuru'],
    'dusman' => $_POST['ayar_dusman']
));
```